# Adding Custom Key-bindings to XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to add a group of custom key-bindings to Xcode 6. I've looked up in the past posts and discovered to do this you need to edit the Default.idekeybindings file located in your **Xcode -> UserData -> KeyBindings -> Default.ideakeybindings**

I have edited this according to how it was done in the previous versions, but when I go into the **preferences -> keybindings** within Xcode I am not able to find the custom action I defined. I would ideally like to make a one key "copy line", "cut line", "duplicate line" and some other useful keybindings I've grown to like while using Sublime and Atom. I've included my .ideakeybindings edited file contents below for reference to what I'm trying to do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>My Custom Actions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Delete Current Line/Selection</key>
        <string>deleteToEndOfLine:, deleteToBeginningOfParagraph:</string>
        <key>Duplicate Line</key>
        <string>selectLine:, copy:, moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:, paste:</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did this on Xcode 7:

- Close Xcode
- Open the file /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Resources/IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist with sudo privileges (be sure to use the correct app-directory for the version of Xcode you are using---for Xcode 6.3 beta mine was Xcode-Beta.app)
- Add your custom commands, save and then start Xcode.
- Set key bindings in Xcode preferences

I added this section:

```
<key>My Custom Commands</key>
<dict>
    <key>Insert New Line Below</key>
    <string>moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:</string>
    <key>Insert New Line Above</key>
    <string>moveUp:, moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:</string>
    <key>Duplicate Current Line</key>
    <string>moveToBeginningOfLine:, deleteToEndOfLine:, yank:, insertNewline:, moveToBeginningOfLine:, yank:</string>
    <key>Delete Current Line</key>
    <string>selectLine:, delete:</string>
    <key>Cut Current Line</key>
    <string>selectLine:, cut:</string>
    <key>Copy Current Line</key>
    <string>setMark:, selectLine:, copy:, moveToEndOfLine:, swapWithMark:</string>
    <key>Paste At Beginning Of Line</key>
    <string>moveToBeginningOfLine:, paste:</string>
</dict>
```

As this gets overwritten every time a new version of Xcode is installed, a user settings location for the custom commands would really be appreciated if someone knows where to add them in the user dir.

Comment: Awesome job, I'm gonna look into this on Tuesday at work and get back to you on how it worked (I'll accept or comment depending on what goes on. Thanks for your help)

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly. For those who are newer to mac than myself, cd into / to get to the MacHD and then go into applications, otherwise you won't get all of the applications in the list.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'm still learning my way around a Mac too - for those who also couldn't figure out how to access this file via Finder ("you don't have permission to see its contents" message), I was able to access this via Terminal using: "cd /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Resources" (make sure you use the right Xcode app!), and then opening the file in a text editor (for example TextWrangler) using: "open -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist".

Comment: I don't have sudo rights, is there no way I can add this somewhere in a config file of my ~/ ?

Comment: I have searched for such a location as every new version of XCode overwrites the settings in the above mentioned IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist. So if you ever discover another solution, at least I would really want to know the answer. So: AFAIK there i no such solution which of course doesn't mean that a solution doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the following for years because I came from Eclipse camp and do like "Duplicate Current Line Up" and "Duplicate Current Line Down" very much.
Note "Xcode.app" could be "Xcode62.app" or "Xcode63.app" depending on how you renamed it.

```
sudo vim /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Resources/IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist

<key>Customized</key>
<dict>
    <key>Duplicate Current Line Up</key>
    <string>moveToBeginningOfLine:, deleteToEndOfLine:, yank:, insertNewline:, moveToBeginningOfLine:, yank:, moveUp:</string>
    <key>Duplicate Current Line Down</key>
    <string>moveToBeginningOfLine:, deleteToEndOfLine:, yank:, insertNewline:, moveToBeginningOfLine:, yank:</string>
    <key>Delete Current Line</key>
    <string>deleteToBeginningOfLine:, moveToEndOfLine:, deleteToBeginningOfLine:, deleteBackward:, moveDown:, moveToBeginningOfLine:</string>
</dict>
```

Restart Xcode | Preferences | Key Bindings | All

search "Duplicate"

search "Current"

then input your favorite shortcut key bindings.

I learnt this trick from somewhere in SO - thx a lot to the original poster. It works on Xcode 6.3 latest beta, Xcode 6.2, 6.1 and previous Xcode versions.